# can't update or upgrade in termux

Tags: openssl, smartphone, termux

whenever i wnat to update my package or upgrade, trmux just show me **0% [Working]** i serche about it and find some answer `termux-change-repo` make termux to use another repository for package **but**
again i saw this error **0% [Working]** i tryed every repository but none of them make any deffernt fo me and for example with grimler repositoy i saw this

```
Grimler's mirrors selected
    Changing main repository                                   Changing game repository
    Changing science repository
[*] Running apt update
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found: needed by /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libcurl.so in namespace (default)
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/apt/methods/https": library "libssl.so.1.1" not found: needed by /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libcurl.so in namespace (default)
0% [Working]
```

but i search about it more and find some new answer
this is a solotion for update package it doesn't work  because. SSL is broken.
so

you must  download  openssl debs "manually" through curl or browser from
[https://packages.termux.dev/apt/termux-main/pool/main/a/apt/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and [https://packages.termux.dev/apt/termux-main/pool/main/o/openssl/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/),
and
install with `dpkg -i /path/to/downloaded/debs`
**but ** you see this new error `dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/path/to/downloaded/debs': No such file or directory`
and...

## i love linux . epicially in my phone "termux" and im happy to solve my problem and the other to improve useing this app :)

Answer (score -1):

a friend do me a favour and help me in this way so I want to share my experience
I start from the last command that we try `dpkg -i /path/to/downloaded/debs`
adapt on friend's guide
**"Well, the error message says it all. Replace /path/to/downloaded/debs with the paths to the debs you downloaded."**
so I do that .i change my path to  /storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_arm.deb and here is the command
`dpkg -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_arm.deb`
and I saw

> dpkg-split: error: failed to read archive
> '/storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_arm.deb': Permission denied
> dpkg: error processing archive
> /storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_arm.deb (--install):
> subprocess dpkg-split returned error exit status 2 Errors were
> encountered while processing:
> /storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_arm.deb

at first I think my phone must be root but
after helping from my friend I get the reason "Run termux-setup-storage to give termux access to shared storage."
I must run `termux-setup-storage`
so it make this command work (dpkg -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_arm.deb)
also the problem is on
error sayed me to use another file from the repository
error sayed the file must be aarc64 no arm
so I do it `dpkg -i /storage/emulated/0/Download/apt_2.5.6_aarch64.deb`
and the new error is :))))

> dpkg: considering removing game-repo in favour of apt ... dpkg: yes,
> will remove game-repo in favour of apt dpkg: considering removing
> science-repo in favour of apt ... dpkg: yes, will remove science-repo
> in favour of apt (Reading database ... 14055 files and directories
> currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
> .../Download/apt_2.5.6_aarch64.deb ... Unpacking apt (2.5.6) over
> (1.4.10-6) ... dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt:
> apt depends on libgnutls; however:   Package libgnutls is not
> installed.  apt depends on liblz4; however:   Package liblz4 is not
> installed.  apt depends on xxhash; however:   Package xxhash is not
> installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package apt (--install):  dependency problems -
> leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for man (1.14.6) ... Errors
> were encountered while processing:  apt

it seemed that  I must install libgnutls , liblz4 and xxhash
I think that's right, I download those dependencies as well. and
I repeat this command for the `dpkg -i ******`